# Adding Hibernate 3.5.x to a maven pom.xml build

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

I added the JBoss Maven repo to my pom.xml file like this...

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>        
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

And I added Hibernate itself like this...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I try to build my application I see this error....

```
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2//org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.1-Final/hibernate-3.5.1-Final.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.1-Final' in repository jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.1-Final/hibernate-3.5.1-Final.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.1-Final' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.1-Final

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate -Dversion=3.5.1-Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate -Dversion=3.5.1-Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) stakeholdersupdate:stakeholdersupdate:war:1.0
    2) org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.1-Final

----------
1 required artifact is missing.
```

Comment: Kindly note that all future JBoss artifacts will not be available in the old repository.
JBoss is moving to a [new maven repository infrastructure](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2010/04/20/announcement--new-maven-repository-infrastructure).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [seanizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018719/adding-hibernate-3-5-x-to-a-maven-pom-xml-build/3018770#3018770) mentioned, the `org.hibernate:hibernate:pom:3.5.1-Final` artifact is an aggregating modules of type `pom` (it aggregates the Hibernate Core modules). So you could indeed depend on it by specifying a `<type>pom</type>`. But I would personally declare a dependency on the wanted module, for example for Hibernate Entity Manager:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Or for Hibernate Core:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: that's right of course. I just answered the question, while providing the answer to an implied better question would have been the way to go :-)

Comment: @BalusC: I took a screenshot! >:)

Answer (score 10):

the hibernate artifact is of type pom (meaning it is only a wrapper for other projects). do this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

(if you leave out the type, maven will try to resolve the artifact as a jar, which doesn't exist in this case)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to add Hibernate and JPA 2 to my project

```
. . .

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss</id>
        <name>The "public-jboss" repository group provides a combined view all JBoss community project artifacts</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    . . .

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    . . .

</dependencies>

. . .
```