# Hibernate's Session exception

Tags: java, hibernate

Im new in hebirnate.  Try execute example code.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Configuration problem: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

public static Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this Thread has none yet
    if (s == null) {
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}

public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    session.set(null);
    if (s != null)
        s.close();
}
}


public class javism_jaxb_xml_to_object {
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
            javism_jaxb cust = new javism_jaxb();
            cust.setName("Vasay");
            cust.setId(1);
            cust.setAge(34);
            session.save(cust);
            tx.commit();
}
}
```

But get exeption

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:111)
at test.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
at test.javism_jaxb_xml_to_object.main(javism_jaxb_xml_to_object.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 3 more
```

What im doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After adding commons-logging-1.1.1.jar in classpath. And refreshing hibernate3.jar from 3.0.3 to 3.5 i get another exeption

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
at test.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
at test.javism_jaxb_xml_to_object.main(javism_jaxb_xml_to_object.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 2 more
```

but if i use hibernate3.jar version 3.0.3 i get this

```
15.08.2012 11:01:30 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.0.3
15.08.2012 11:01:30 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
15.08.2012 11:01:30 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using CGLIB reflection optimizer
15.08.2012 11:01:30 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
15.08.2012 11:01:30 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
15.08.2012 11:01:30 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add apache commons logging jar in your classpath if you have it. Otherwise download it from [apache](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) and add it in your project and add it in project's classpth.

**UPDATE**

download dom4j library [here](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) and add it in classpath.

**UPDATE2**

INFO: Hibernate 3.0.3  --> INFO LOG SHOWING hibernate version you are using.

INFO: hibernate.properties not found  -->  INFO LOG SHOWING `hibernate.properties` not found. This is an alternate way to give hibernate properties, you do provide these properties in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

For more info check [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Comment: Sorry its not help. I get another exeption. Please look at UPDATE

Comment: Now on path of adding of million libraryes. I hope its end soon.

Comment: Rrrrrr stakoverflow not give me edit question so i put new problem here.  New exeption.`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit`. Maybe you can upload all librarys needed for hibernate works anywhere?

Comment: i change version from 3.0.3 to 3.5. But i cant edit question((

Answer (score 1):

If you are just making a sample project for trying out hibernate, then what Nandkumar suggested is ok, just keep adding jars of the classes that are reported in `NoClassDefFoundError`.

This process is very tedious, ideally you should use a dependency management tool like maven which can resolve all the dependencies of Hibernate (or any other such framework). This thread can help you setup maven for using hibernate. It will also help you while moving across versions of hibernate as well

[Adding Hibernate 3.5.x to a maven pom.xml build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018719/adding-hibernate-3-5-x-to-a-maven-pom-xml-build)